# How to calculate floating point numbers in small memory

Tags: floating-point

There are two locations in small memory 6 and 7:

```
  0110 | 1111 1110 1101 0011
  0111 | 0000 0110 1101 1001
```

Interpret locations 6 and 7 as an IEEE floating point number. 
Location 6 contains number [15:0] and location 7 contains number [16:31].

---

My attempt

```
Floating Point -
   Locations 6 and 7: 0000 0110 1101 1001 1111 1110 1101 0011
   The number represented is 1.101 1001 1111 1110 1101 0011 × 2^(-114)
```

Is my answer correct?
I am unsure exactly what the [16:31] and [15:0] relate to/mean?

Comment: Is the number represented the same still? Would my bit represtion by correct if it were [31:16] rather than [16:31]

Comment: Ignore my previous (deleted) comment - you might find this helpful: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html